# Is there a way to setup custom triggers in Visual Studio Team Services/TFS?

Tags: tfs, version-control, azure-devops

I use VSTS/TFS for work and side projects and I wanted to setup a trigger/rule that would automatically move stories into a certain iteration when I move them from "New" to "Approved" or whatever column is associated with an active state. I know how to change the iteration manually but it would be way easier if there was a way to say something like this psuedocode:

```
if (workItem.State == "Active") {MoveToIterationActiveForTodaysDate();}
```

Ideally too, if this isn't too picky, I would like it to only run on initial move so I can reassign to a different iteration later if I wanted to.

If anyone has an easier way to do this too that accomplishes the same thing (moving items to an iteration without having to manually activate the story and move it to the desired iteration) that would work as well. I'm still figuring out the ideal way to manage VSTS/TFS. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using VSTS is able to [customizable work item rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/release-notes/2017/aug-28-team-services#customizable-work-item-rules).

> Whether it be automatically setting the value of certain work item
>   fields or defining the behavior of those fields in specific states,
>   project admins can now use rules to automate the behavior of work item
>   fields and ease the burden on their teams.

More details please refer this tutorial: [Add a rule to a work item type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/process/custom-rules)

However, it works with fields in the work item, not able to move work item to different iteration or area directly.

There is no out of box feature could achieve your requirement with TFS and VSTS  for now. You may have to customize TFS events/actions to achieve the same feature as right click the work item--select move iteration--choose iteration.

Moreover, you could also use some 3-rd party extensions/tools such as Giulio
 suggested TFS Aggregator.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, there is no built-in automation, so the community wrote some tools that react at TFS/VSTS events and run scripts.
I can suggest [TFS Aggregator](http://tfsaggregator.github.io/) which is used by many organization throughout the world: I am one of the core contributor.